# How to add elements randomly into a vector using push_back

Tags: c++, class, vector, std

As the Title states, I've been having trouble with adding random numbers as the elements into a vector of integer type. I included the time and stdlib libraries to work in conjunction with the vector library.

My attempt(using classes) so far has been:

To pass in a vector by reference into a function that adds random elements into a vector. In addition, passing a in reference to a variable I want to update, and using a pointer declared in the class and defined in the constructor to hold the memory address of the variable(same one that is was referenced to in previous lines).

```
class PlayerHand

{ 
     public:
           playerHand();
           void populateHand(vector<int>&, int&)

     private:
             vector<int> &refVector; 
             int *pPointer;
             int giveCard;
 };

playerHand::playerHand()

{
   srand((time(NULL)));     
   giveCard = (rand() % 14) + 1;

   pPointer = &giveCard;
}


void playerHand::populateHand(vector<int> &refVector, int &refGiveCard)

{ for( int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{

    refVector.push_back(*pPointer); //dereference thepointer to store value in giveCard
    srand(time(0));                      
    refGiveCard = (rand() %14) + 1;  /*Here is where I'm trying to update the reference
                                     so before the next loop, the reference should have
                                     a new updated value*/

    cout << refVector.at(i) << " ";
 }
 }
```

So after I compile the code, the elements in the vector are all the same number, and not different. What mistake in the code am I making?

Comment: they are all equal to the same `givecard`.. what are you trying to achieve here..?

Comment: You use `refVector` as the name of a data member and as the name of a local variable in a member function. Don't do that.

Comment: How do you call `populateHand`?

Comment: @KarthikT - I'm trying to add random numbers that represent cards into a player's hand, I'm modeling the crazy eight's card game, so i wanted to put the value of giveCard in the function via pPointer, and then use the reference (refGiveCard ) to update the value of giveCard to a totally different number

Comment: @jogojapan - thanks for the heads up, by the way, I call populateHand like a regular function in the main function on the stack.

Comment: @Zelbert just call it without parameters and fill in random values.

Comment: @Zelbert Yes, what I meant was, what arguments to you call it with? What does the call look like exactly?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i missed what you were really saying. here it is.      distributeCard start;
playerHand theHand;

playerHand *pointerPHand = new playerHand;
distributeCard *pointerDistributeCard = new distributeCard;

theHand.populateHand(pointerPHand->refVector, pointerDistributeCard->giveCard);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `pPointer`, `giveCard` and `refGiveCard` may not refer to the same memory location. As jogojapan & Karthik pointed out you may also be adding the values to a different vector. You don't show all the code for this so it's hard to tell. Assuming they all *do* refer to the same memory location and you are adding the values to the correct vector your issue is caused by the call to `srand()`.

The problem is that you are [almost] always seeding the random number generator with the same value. This is because when you call `time(0)` it returns the elapsed time in seconds. When you call it repeatedly and very quickly it will return the same value until the clock increments to the next second.

Typically you will call `srand()` at the beginning of your program or when you really *need* to reseed the RNG.

Remove the call to `srand()` from `playerHand()` and `populateHand()` and place it in `main()` and it should take care of you problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't show the rest of the code ( I wanted to shorten the load as best as possible ), but I will do as you suggested with srand().

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `refGiveCard`, but you are adding `giveCard`. Therefore they are all the same value.

There is also the fact that you are adding to a different vector than you might expect as jogojapan pointed out.